# Reducing Dataset Using SAS Programming

Tags: sas, macros, sas-macro, proc, proc-sql

I have a dataset i.e. -

```
Coverage_Start  Termination_Date    Member_Id
24-Jul-19       1-Jun-21            42968701
24-Jul-19       1-Mar-21            42968701
29-Feb-20       1-Mar-20            42968701
16-Feb-19       1-Mar-19            42968701
1-Mar-17        1-Mar-18            42968701
1-Mar-16        1-Mar-17            42968701
1-Dec-15        31-Dec-16           42968701
```

I want to reduce this dataset, suppose in last three rows minimum coverage_start- 1-Dec-15 and maximum termination_date- 1-Mar-18, so I want to combine all three bottom rows because it has continuous coverage.
As result the bottom three rows will be reduced to "1-Dec-15  1-Mar-18  42968701".

Reduced Dataset should be like -

```
Coverage_Start  Termination_Date    Member_Id
24-Jun-19       1-Jun-21            42968701
16-Feb-19       1-Mar-19            42968701
1-Dec-15        1-Mar-18            42968701
```

I want to achieve this task using SAS programming.
Can anyone please help me with this? I'm trying this since a very log time but couldn't achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it.  I do not get same answer as you for rng 2 not sure if I don't understand or you have it wrong.

```
proc datasets kill nolist; quit;
/*
Coverage_Start  Termination_Date    Member_Id
29-Feb-20       1-Jun-21            42968701
16-Feb-19       1-Mar-19            42968701
1-Dec-15        1-Mar-18            42968701
*/
filename FT15F001 temp;
data cover0(keep=id date) / view=cover0;
   infile FT15F001 firstobs=2;
   input (start term) (:date.) id:$10.;
   do date=start to term;
      output;
      end;
   format date date11.;
   parmcards;
Coverage_Start  Termination_Date    Member_Id
24-Jul-19       1-Jun-21            42968701
24-Jul-19       1-Mar-21            42968701
29-Feb-20       1-Mar-20            42968701
16-Feb-19       1-Mar-19            42968701
1-Mar-17        1-Mar-18            42968701
1-Mar-16        1-Mar-17            42968701
1-Dec-15        31-Dec-16           42968701
;;;;
   run;
proc sort nodupkey data=cover0 out=cover1;
   by id date;
   run;

data cover2/ view=cover2;
   set cover1;
   by id;
   dif = dif(date);
   if first.id then do;
      dif=1;
      rng = 0;
      end;
   if dif ne 1 then rng + 1;
   run;

proc summary data=cover2 nway missing;
   class id;
   class rng / descend;
   output out=reduce(drop=_type_) min(date)=Start max(date)=Term;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]

Comment: It works but not efficient one if you work with millions of rows. Is there any other way of doing it? Can we use lag function on termination date and then find the difference between the coverage start and termination then we put a condition if difference <= 1 the set coverage_min= min(coverage_start) and termination=max(termination)  and when difference >1 we update the coverage_min to a new minimum date.